# Pandas create new column based on a rows in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have following classes in pandas column :
Married-civilian spouse present ,Never married , Married-spouse absent, Married-A F spouse present                 ,Divorced, Widowed, Separated  .

Based on it create new column in where (Married-civilian spouse present ,Never married , Married-spouse absent) will be replaced by 1 and rest of the rows by 0.

I tried following but all rows are being mapped to 0 and none of the rows are getting mapped to 1.

```py
df_filtered['is_married'] = df_filtered['marital_status'].apply(lambda status: 1 if (status == "Married-civilian spouse present" or status == "Married-spouse absent" or status=="Married-A F spouse present") else 0 )
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
df_filtered['is_married'] = df_filtered['marital_status'].isin(['Married-civilian spouse present', 'Married-spouse absent', 'Married-A F spouse present']).astype(int)
```